# How do the forces involved in EMR continue to occilate past emmision of a photon

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, photons, electrons

If electric fields are created by an accelerated charged particle, such as an electron, and magnetic fields are generated by electric fields in motion, what are the individual fields that make up Electromagnetic Radiation oscillating between? What is the Y axis in their sinusoid function measuring, and how does that continue to oscilate in the absense of moving charge once the photo is emited?
Is the electronic field aspect oscilating between a negative and positive charge relevant to overall energy levels, or is it confined to one side of that?
I am asking as I have an incomplete understanding of how a photon, without a charge, continues to oscilate at the speec of light.
I fully expect that I have an oversimplified understanding of both repsective fields, and I hope to learn what unknown forces are at play.

Comment: [Do Electromagnetic Waves really propagate through continuous Induction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78537/do-electromagnetic-waves-really-propagate-through-continuous-induction)